# describing SSM parameter: ParameterNotFound used the data block to retrieve the value second time in a different component

Tags: amazon-web-services, parameters, terraform, aws-ssm

We are using Terraform scaffold with version 1.5.7

I have successfully created an AWS SSM parameter within one of our existing components `subnets` using the `resource "aws_ssm_parameter"` block.

`components/subnets/subnet.tf`

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "ssm_public_subnet" {
  name        = "public-subnet-irl"
  description = "public subnet"
  type        = "String"
  value       = join(",", module.vpc_core.subnet_ids)
}
```

I attempted to reference this parameter in a different component `core` using the `data "aws_ssm_parameter"` block, which worked as expected.

`components/core/data.tf`

```
data "aws_ssm_parameter" "ssm_public_subnet" {
  name = "public-subnet-irl"
}
```

However, when I tried to use the same data block in same region yet another different component `lambda`, I encountered a `describing SSM parameter (public-subnet-irl): ParameterNotFound` error, despite the presence of the parameter in the AWS console.
`components/lambda/data.tf`

```
data "aws_ssm_parameter" "ssm_public_subnet" {
  name = "public-subnet-irl"
}
```

`error`

```
│ Error: describing SSM parameter (public-subnet-irl): ParameterNotFound:
│
│   with data.aws_ssm_parameter.ssm_public_subnet,
│   on data.tf line 11, in data "aws_ssm_parameter" "ssm_public_subnet":
│   11: data "aws_ssm_parameter" "ssm_public_subnet" {
│
╵
ERROR: Terraform plan failed
```

I have also tried to run terraform apply but got the same error message

Expected scenario to use the data block to retrieve the value second time in a different component

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure that Lambda is in the same region?

Comment: Is the lambda component actually deployed? I have seen this several times where people use data lookups but they way the TF graph builds the tree the data look up can happen before the resource is deployed.

Comment: @MarkoE I'm positive that, all the above mention components are to deploy in same region.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle No, I was getting error message, when I'm trying to deploy lambda component.

Comment: If the lamba component is not deployed then the data lookup will fail since the lambda doesn't exist.

Comment: I want to deploy 
```resource "aws_lambda_function" "example" {
 ..
  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids         = [data.aws_ssm_parameter.ssm_public_subnet.value]   
  }```
I get error when it trying to retrieve the value of `data.aws_ssm_parameter.ssm_public_subnet.value`
@ChrisDoyle